# A bounty set by the Community user?

Tags: discussion, moderation, bounty, community-user

See [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15443/do-we-need-maxwells-equations-since-they-fail-to-account-for-an-experimental-fa).

The question sits on a +2 -18 vote status, but has +100 bounty on it, from "Community". Digging further into it leads me to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community), which seems to suggest that Community is a kind of a bot. However -

If it is a bot and,

1) has 1 rep, what is the source of the bounty amount?

2) how does it write that human-like comment in the bounty notice -

> That guy was just confused. Why so many downvotes?

Is Community really a bot, or some SE moderator disguised as a bot? Does it really work as per some algorithms, or is there a human touch to it?

(Except of course that algorithm might be written by a human, but is that comment algorithm generated?)

Comment: As you can see here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community, the community account has moderator privileges, but it is not a real person.

Comment: @JamalS - Yes, but your link is just my ''leads me to [this] (link)''. :)

Comment: @Emilio - I get your point. No, I'm not rolling back. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that question, the bounty was issued by a user with 100+ reputation. The user has (been) deleted the account after that. The only purpose for the bounty is to raise the attention of the most downvoted question as said in the bounty description. As I remember, the user is from other SE and get 100 association bonus so it is not surprised that the user disappear after that.

The Community is a bot, and it will take over anything that is not associated to anyone anymore. Mod can tell you more on it.

Comment: Yes, then it makes sense. OK maybe you saw the bounty thing before I did.